# c program hangs/loops when "sudo -s" command is executed

Tags: c, linux, sudo, command-line-interface

I'm currently writing a program  that will run multiple commands (in one line) in the CLI  using C.

The first command that I need to run is `sudo -s`. So I run this command alone to test if the program is running, but the program hangs while running this command. I wanted to know if the problem is the program or the command, so I run `ls`. The program works perfectly when I run the `ls` command so I assume that something is wrong with `sudo -s` command, maybe I need to do something with that command so that it will run in the CLI.

Here's the function that accepts the command:

```
int executeCommand(char *command, char *result)
{
    /*This function runs a command./*/
    /*The return value is the output of command*/

    int nSuccess = -1;
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    char buffer[1035];

    if (command == NULL)
        render("Command is null");

    if (result == NULL)
        render("result is null");
    if (command!=NULL && result!=NULL)
    {
        fp=popen(command,"r");
        if(fp!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(result,"\0");
            while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1,fp)!=NULL)
            {
                strcat(result,buffer);
            }
            pclose(fp);
        }   nSuccess=0;

    }

    return nSuccess;
}
```

BTW, I'm doing a web app, the user will write the command that he wants to execute. The input will be sent to server via `ajax` using a `POST` request. And the server runs on Linux.

Comment: did you run ls with option? `ls -n` ?

Comment: a) This looks like a very dangerous web app to write. b) Your sudo -s is probably hanging because you are starting a new shell and your program is still attached to the old one.

Comment: How have you configured sudo? In the default configuration it will try to read a password from the terminal device, which you can't supply through popen.

Comment: @LearningC i just did, the program is working using that command

Comment: @srhsnl ya ok. for `sudo` command you'll nedd to enter password. it will wait for password to be entered right? it doesnt affect your code or you managed it?

Comment: @LearningC okay, but when I try to manually run sudo -s, it isnt asking for a password so I assume that, programmatically, It wont ask for my password as well. besides, if it needs my password, it will prompt something like "password for user" msg right? but I didnt see anything, its as if the program hangs

Comment: Can you consider any potential security risks from allowing `sudo -s` to run without actually asking the user for a password?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -s` will prompt for a password and won't return a result immediately.

Comment: okay, but when I try to manually run sudo -s, it isnt asking for a password so I assume that, programmatically, It wont ask for my password as well. besides, if it needs my password, it will prompt something like "password for user" msg right? but I didnt see anything, its as if the program hangs

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -s
```

will require the password so the program running this command may wait for password to be entered

Comment: okay, but when I try to manually run sudo -s, it isnt asking for a password so I assume that, programmatically, It wont ask for my password as well. besides, if it needs my password, it will prompt something like "password for user" msg right? but I didnt see anything, its as if the program hangs